# Displaying the tablix structure for No data values in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a SSRS report in which I have a parameter with a list of names, In which a multiple value can be selected by the user. I gave title of the report using an expression where it shows "Result for SELECTED NAME" and applied page break such that each value is displayed on a new page.

But when i select all the values at a time, the report is only displaying the results for the names only for whom the data is available.

I would like to display the title as "Result for SELECTED NAME"(remember this is for the values with no data along with the values with data, each on new page) and tablix structure with a NoRowmessage.

I am really struggling on this since two days!!

Can any one help me?? Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at your query. Is your query returning a row for each name, or only rows where the names exist? If you can, change the structure of your query to return the names, left joined to your actual query.

Here's some simple code that captures the idea:

```
SELECT names.Lastname, names,Firstname, data.* 
from (select distinct name from name table) as names
left join (previous query) as data on data.nameID = names.nameID
```

Comment: I got it, yes you are right my query doesn't contain all the names that i have given in the parameter. Thank you.

But I didn't understand the query though, I am sorry I am kind of new to sql, so if you can explain more about the query that would be great.

Comment: You're welcome. Basically, what you need to do in your query is create two query. One query is responsible for bringing back all the names that you want to display. The second query is your original query, which only has data for certain users. Could you provide an example table name? I can help you work through it. Start by writing the two separate queries and verify they have the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did figured it out and it worked.